# TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

The seemingly simple code below throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nirmal/process.py", line 165, in <module>
    'time_diff': f.last(adf['time_diff']).over(window_device_rows)
TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'this_campaign'
```

### Code:

```
# Function to flag network timeouts
def flag_network_timeout(**kwargs):
    if kwargs['this_network'] != kwargs['last_network'] \
            or kwargs['this_campaign'] != kwargs['last_campaign'] \
            or kwargs['this_adgroup'] != kwargs['last_adgroup'] \
            or kwargs['this_creative'] != kwargs['last_creative'] \
            or kwargs['time_diff'] > network_timeout:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
flag_network_timeout = f.udf(flag_network_timeout, IntegerType())

# Column spec to go over the device events and flag network resets
network_timeout_flag = flag_network_timeout(**{
    'last_network': f.first(adf['network']).over(window_device_rows),
    'last_campaign': f.first(adf['campaign']).over(window_device_rows),
    'last_adgroup': f.first(adf['adgroup']).over(window_device_rows),
    'last_creative': f.first(adf['creative']).over(window_device_rows),
    'this_network': f.last(adf['network']).over(window_device_rows),
    'this_campaign': f.last(adf['campaign']).over(window_device_rows),
    'this_adgroup': f.last(adf['adgroup']).over(window_device_rows),
    'this_creative': f.last(adf['creative']).over(window_device_rows),
    'time_diff': f.last(adf['time_diff']).over(window_device_rows)
})

# Update dataframe with the new columns
adf = adf.select('*', network_timeout_flag.alias('network_timeout'))
```

What am I doing wrong please? Thank you.

Comment: To whoever who voted to close this, care to explain how this is too broad? The error is specific, and the code is specific to the error.

Comment: poorly framed question - not easily searcheable

Comment: @muon How? The tags say define all the languages. The title contains the exact error message. The body contains the problem. This definitely doesn't warrant a closure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You get an exception because [`UserDefinedFunction.__call__`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/14869ae64eb27830179d4954a5dc3e0a1e1330b4/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py#L1750) supports only varargs and not keyword args.

```
def __call__(self, *cols):
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    jc = self._judf.apply(_to_seq(sc, cols, _to_java_column))
    return Column(jc)
```

At much more basic level UDF can receive only `Column` arguments, which will be expanded to their corresponding value on runtime, and not standard Python objects.

Personally I wouldn't use `**kwargs` for this at all, but ignoring that you can achieve what you want by composing SQL expressions:

```
def flag_network_timeout_(**kwargs):

    cond = (
        (kwargs['this_network'] != kwargs['last_network']) |
        (kwargs['this_campaign'] != kwargs['last_campaign']) |
        (kwargs['this_adgroup'] != kwargs['last_adgroup']) |
        (kwargs['this_creative'] != kwargs['last_creative']) |
        (kwargs['time_diff'] > network_timeout))

    return f.when(cond, 1).otherwise(0)
```

Comment: "because UserDefinedFunction.__call__ supports only varargs and not keyword args". Thank you. That was it! I don't think I would have captured it myself.

Comment: The second part is much more important IMHO :) Whenever you can choose between UDF and composing SQL expression the former one should always be your first choice. UDFs, especially Python ones, have quite a few ugly properties.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't get the second part. How different it is from the UDF?

Comment: Off the top of my head: UDF a) has to move data from off-heap storage b) move data from JVM to Python converting types on the way c) has to move data back to JVM once again using SerDe to convert types d) introduces nondeterministic breakpoint in the execution plan. e) doesn't benefit from codegen. The alternative solution (lets call it `flag_network_timeout_`) uses Python only to build SQL expression and limits Python code to driver only.

Comment: This is great! I converted all my UDF to SQL expressions and ended up getting 22% increased performance (from 44 minutes to 34 minutes for the script to complete). Thanks for your very good help!

Comment: thanks for pointing out `supports only varargs and not keyword args.`

Comment: I have no "kwargs" at all in my code but get the same error.